# JavaScript switch statement nested within a function

Tags: javascript

```
var movie = prompt("Type the movie title you want reviewed");
var getReview = function(movie){
switch(movie){
    case 'Matrix':
        return "good trip out";
        break;
    case 'Princess Bride':
        return "awesome date night movie";
        break;
    case 'Welcome to America':
        return "Amjad's favorite";
        break;
    case 'Remember the Titans':
        return "love the sports";
        break;
    case 'Why do I look like I'm 12?':
        return "The Ryan and Zach story";
        break;
    case 'Fighting Kangaroos in the wild':
        return "Token Australian movie for Leng";
        break;
    default:
        return "I don't know!";
    }
};
```

When I submit the above code, I get the error message: SyntaxError - missing : after case label. What's the problem with the syntax?

Comment: Very simple syntax error. ```case 'Why do I look like I'm 12?':``` should be ```case "Why do I look like I'm 12?":```

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the syntax highlighting.  Unless you understand why it's highlighting stuff wrong, chances are it's your code -- and not the highlighter -- that's broken.

Comment: How did this get a +1 xD

Answer (score 4):

change

```
case 'Why do I look like I'm 12?':
```

to

```
case 'Why do I look like I\'m 12?':
```

Answer (score 2):

Quote `'Why do I look like I'm 12?':` to `'Why do I look like I\'m 12?':`. Also, you don't need `break` after return

Comment: get the optimizer do it's job ... ;-)

Comment: @AxelAmthor Adding `break` after `return` makes a difference? I didn't know that, or am I missing the point :P

Comment: @Raekye: Not in a decent JS implementation, it doesn't.  It'll be entirely irrelevant, and may even be marked as unreachable code in some IDEs.

Comment: That was a joke, but obviously I'm the only one laughing here ...

Comment: @AxelAmthor: I was semi thinking you were joking...but eh.  I've had to deal with so many ricers lately that i have to err on the side of believing people are actually serious about stuff like that...lest i have to deal with a generation of people littering their code with stuff like that later.  :P

Comment: @AxelAmthor haha sorry, I wasn't sure about it, I missed the point xD

Answer (score 2):

```
case 'Why do I look like I'm 12?':
```

change that into that :

```
case 'Why do I look like I\'m 12?':
```

you have a quoting issue

Answer (score 1):

JS thinks you are closing the string at `Why do I look like I'`. To avoid this, you have to escape the apostrophe, using `\`:

```
case 'Why do I look like I\'m 12?':
```